# Creating NSToolbar style buttons

Tags: cocoa, nstoolbar

Is there a bevel style that can replicate NSToolbar style of buttons that are used, for instance, in the Safari's preferences window to switch between different panes?

I need to replicate NSToolbar in an NSView using NSButtons. I understand that I should probably be using NSTabView, but I'd like to implement the look of xcode's left pane. Any tips here would be appreciated greatly.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing built-in, you'd have to create the images yourself. However, replicating the behaviour is straightforward.

You could simply use a single-row `NSMatrix` of `NSButton` objects. Just give the buttons an image and an alternate image (for the highlighted state) and set the matrix mode to `NSRadioModeMatrix`.